# Cannot query Azure Data Warehouse tables using Python in a GitHub action

Tags: python, azure, github-actions

## Background

I am able to query various tables from my company's Azure Data Warehouse locally in Visual Studio Code with the following function:

```py
def query_all_from_table(self, database, table):
    connection_string = (
            'DRIVER=SQL Server;'
            'SERVER=azr-warehouse;'
            f'DATABASE={database};'
            f'UID={os.getenv("AZURE_USER")};'
            f'PWD={os.getenv("AZURE_PW")};'
            'TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
            'Connection Timeout=60;'
        )

        try:
            # Connect to Azure Data Warehouse
            conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

            # Query all
            sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM {table}"

            # Execute the query
            data = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)

            conn.close()

            return data

        except for pyodbc.Error as e:
            print('Error connecting to Azure Data Warehouse:', e)
                
        return pd.DataFrame()
```

Where the `AZUER_USER` and `AZURE_PW` are my company SSO credentials.

## Problem

When I try to use this function in a Github action, I get the following error:

```
Error connecting to Azure Data Warehouse: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Below is my YML file for the action:

```yaml
name: Update

on:
    push:
      branches:
        - main
    schedule:
      - cron: '0 8 * * *' 
    workflow_dispatch:  # Allow manual triggering from GitHub UI

jobs:
  run_query:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install ODBC Driver for SQL Server
        run: sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev odbcinst odbcinst1debian2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run Python script
        env:
            AZURE_USER_HAGEN: ${{ secrets.AZURE_USER_HAGEN }}
            AZURE_PW_HAGEN: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PW_HAGEN }}
            FIREBASE_CREDS: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CREDS }}
        run: python update.py
```

## My Attempts at Solution

- tried using `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server as the server name but I get a timeout error

```
Error connecting to Azure Data Warehouse: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

- tried adding `.database.windows.net` but I get the same timeout error

Answer (score 0):

> tried adding  `.database.windows.net`  but I get the same timeout error

You're using "SQL Server" as the driver, but the correct driver name should be "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

Modify **YAML file:**

```py
def query_all_from_table(self, database, table):
    connection_string = (
        'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
        'SERVER=azr-warehouse.database.windows.net;'  # Add your server URL
        'Connection Timeout=30;'  # Adjust this value
        )
```

- Also, add connection timeout in you connection string value because of latency issues also gets timeout errors.

[image]

Sometimes we face the firewall setting error also because of network issues as in above picture.

[image]

- Modify the network protocol in your connection string as below.
  `server_name = "tcp:server-name.database.windows.net"`

Here I am able to create a table by modifying above steps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated my script and YAML file as you suggested and tried running again to see the error. I only get a `Login timeout expired (0)` error and I am not shown any IP addresses to configure access for.